# How to get C++ Errors in a Batch For Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping

I am attempting to process the errors generated when compiling C++ code within a batch script.  I have a for loop similar to the following:

```
@FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('COMMAND TO COMPILE C++') DO @(
  SET MESSAGE=%%A
  SET MESSAGE=!MESSAGE:"='!
  CALL :PRINT "!MESSAGE!"
)
```

The problem I am running into is when I get an error about a template, comparison operators, the exclusive or operator, or the bit shift operators.  In these cases, the error string in %%A contains both quotes and greater than/less than symbols.  For example:

```
error: yada yada TemplateClass<> "Some Message"
error: yada yada operator <<() 'Some Message'
error: yada yada 'operator ^()' "Some Message"
```

My question is this: is it possible to capture the entirety of a message that contains double quotes, single quotes, and less than/greater than characters in the for loop?  What I have tried:

```
:: Fails when %%A contains a quote
SET "MESSAGE=%%A"
:: Fails when %%A contains a quote
SET MESSAGE="%%A"
:: Fails when %%A contains a greater-than symbol
SET MESSAGE=%%A
```

Is there any way for me to capture %%A in another variable, so I can otherwise use this variable elsewhere in the batch file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "correct" way of assigning the value to a variable is `set "message=%%a"`. But when calling the print function, instead of passing the value, pass the variable name (a reference), and dereference the variable inside the function.

And, in your :print function, when accessing the content of the variable use the `!var!` notation to avoid that the special characters are considered part of the command instead of part of the text.

A little sample (dbenham style)

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%f in ('findstr /b /c:":::" "%~f0" ') do (
        set "line=%%f"
        call :print line
    ) 

    exit /b

:print variable
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo( Parameter                     : %~1
    echo( Dereferenced value            : !%~1!
    set "var=!%~1!"
    echo( Variable with the value       : !var!

    echo.

    rem If var contains special characters the following line fails
    rem echo( Variable with the value       : %var%

    endlocal
    goto :EOF


exit /b 

:::This is a plain line
:::This line has special characters !"'#$%&/()=?:
:::This line has more special characters << " >>
:::"This is a double quoted line"
:::'This is a single quoted line'
```